# ng-init not working to initialize data

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, ng-init is not working to initialize data before executing the template.
For Example,
**index.html**

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label label-bold">Shipping First Name :</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input class="control-width" validation-errors="contactData" 
         maxlength="50" type="text" id="shipping_first_name" 
         placeholder="First Name" 
         ng-model="contactData.data.ShopCustomer.shipping_first_name"
         ng-init="contactData.data.ShopCustomer.shipping_first_name='abc'">
    </div>
</div>
```

How do i get the initial value in AngularJS?

Here is the Fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/aasquare3/2XDvt/

Comment: could you share fiddle or plunker demo

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal : This is a simple example Not getting the initialize Value. What is wrong in this code?

Comment: ng-init may be working fine, but something maybe overwriting the model property after ng-init. Once the page loads see the state of you scope model and verify.

Comment: @archna When someone asks you to create a fiddle than that's because he/she wants to help you, so don't be lazy about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58PSH/) - `abc` shows in the textbox/input.

Your fiddle wasn't including Angular, so I added v1.0.3, and specified "No wrap - in <body>".

The `body` tag did not have `ng-app`, so I specified `<body ng-app>` under "Fiddle Options".

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `contactData`, `contactData.data` and `contactData.data.ShopCustomer` have been initialized (to empty objects at the very least) before attempting to set the value of `contactData.data.ShopCustomer.shipping_first_name`?

Comment: You don't need to. AngularJS would create that for you.

Comment: Yes.contactData, contactData.data and contactData.data.ShopCustomer have been initialized empty.